# Resource(25) of type (mysql_result)

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error where it returns Resource(25) of type (mysql_result).

All I'm doing is select something from the database and there is an item in the database.

Query:

```
$s2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `api` ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1");
```

When I var_dump($s2) it returns this:

```
Resource(25) of type (mysql_result)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's exactly what it should be doing. I suggest reading the manual on mysql_query().

Comment: what did you read that says use mysql_query? what did it say to do next ?

Comment: That's exactly it's output.

Comment: Yes. Try reading the next section of your tutorial.

Comment: Please do not write new code using mysql_* functions they are deprecated and should not be used. Use either mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Is is just me, or are there 24 other working queries in this script?

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart, funny. But the resource id is not necessarily sequential. Typically they are shared amongst the server.

Comment: i guess some one should point out that ORDER BY RAND can be be very slow on a large table

Comment: Its a table of 20 @Dragon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resource(25) of type (mysql_result) means your query is valid.

If you want to display data, you can try either of the following:

```
$var = mysql_fetch_array($s2);
echo $var['field_name_here'];
```

or

```
$var = mysql_result($s2, 0, 'field_name_here');
echo $var;
```

As suggested in the comments, you should read the manual thoroughly.
Cheers!

Comment: Error: `mysql_fectch_array` => `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Didn't see that one. Thanks for the correction! It's okay now. :)